# I am trying to delete a user from matillon which I have created by mistake using CURL command

Tags: curl, matillion

So currently there are 2 user with similar id (one without space, other with space) in their ID. So I want to delete the user(other with space) but when I run the Delete Curl command it's not recognizing the userid (with space) in the curl command

command I run:
curl -X DELETE -u "uxyzadmin:Uxyz@xyzpqr" -k  "https://azrqwerty.uxyz.us/rest/v1/userconfig/user/instance?userName=smkum@uxyz.us " -H "Content-Type: application/json"

I tried using %20 like below

"https://azrqwerty.uxyz.us/rest/v1/userconfig/user/instance?userName=smkum@uxyz.us%20" -H "Content-Type: application/json"

Please suggest on how to delete the user "smkum@uxyz.us "

Answer (score 0):

You were on the right lines with the %20. First you can get information on the available endpoints in the [Userconfig API service](https://documentation.matillion.com/docs/2791763) with a GET to /rest/v1/userconfig/user/instance.

According to that, there's a "removeUserPost" service if you `POST` to the /delete path. Note: it's not actually a DELETE for some reason.

With that information, making a POST to these example endpoints worked for me:

```
/rest/v1/userconfig/user/instance/delete?userName=theuser

/rest/v1/userconfig/user/instance/delete?userName=i%20got%20spaces

/rest/v1/userconfig/user/instance/delete?userName=trailingspace%20
```

There are also more Matillion REST API examples in [this article](https://www.matillion.com/resources/blog/data-fabric-integration-using-the-matillion-etl-rest-api) on their site.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I tried the following cmd   curl -X POST -u "pqrstadmin:pqrst@********" -k  "https://azrusexxxxxxx.PQR.us/rest/v1/userconfig/user/instance/delete?userName=XYZ@PQR.us%20" -H "Content-Type: application/json"

And the response I got is:
{"success":false,"msg":"Unable to find user with name [XYZ@PQR.us ].","id":-1}  ----------when i observe the response looks like i am getting an extra dot after square bracket ending. Do you have any insights or suggestion on this please?

Comment: The square brackets are added just for pretty printing. When you go to Admin / User Configuration, is it set to "Internal"? I'm wondering if you have "External" (i.e. LDAP authentication) typical in a clustered setup? If that's the case then users are not managed by Matillion so you can't delete them.